# How to make a FlutterActivity be a MethodCallHandler?

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I made my `FlutterActivity` `MainActivity` a `MethodCallHandler`:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(), MethodCallHandler {
```

so I implemented `onMethodCall`.

However, to be able to process method calls, still something is missing. This is how it's done in a Flutter plugin:

```
class MyPlugin: FlutterPlugin {
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel
  private val LOG_TAG: String = "MyPlugin.kt"
  
  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "myplugin")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  }
```

How can I make my `MainActivity` be the actual `MethodCallHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configureFlutterEngine` provides binding between Dart and native.

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "<your_channel>").setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      // TODO
    }
  }
...
```